# Using AppDomain to load assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, appdomain

Answer to my question my already be on stackoverflow however, I just can't find the right one/not get it to work.

What I'm trying to do is, load the .dll to my Windows Form, use reflection to retrieve method/class names. I have got it to work using `Assembly.LoadFrom` however it's doing exactly what I wanted as this locks the .dll file.

I have read around and found out that `AppDomain` can do the trick however, I just can't get it to do the trick.

Below is the code I have tried however, in `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap`, I don't know which `typeName` it's looking for.

```
var executableFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
               DllPath,
                null,
                new AppDomainSetup
                {
                    ApplicationBase = Path.GetPathRoot(executableFilePath),
                    PrivateBinPathProbe = string.Empty,

                    PrivateBinPath = string.Join(";", DllPath, executableFilePath),
                    ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile,
                });



      var temp = domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(DllPath, typeof(????).FullName, false,
            BindingFlags.Default, null, null, null, null);
```

The .dll I will load at runtime will not be referenced into my Windows Form application.

Comment: Is your Forms-App in the same App-Domain? The newly created one and the stuff loaded into will not be automatically avaialble for the initial app-domain

Comment: How do I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look this thread: [How to Load an Assembly to AppDomain with all references recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658498/how-to-load-assembly-to-appdomain-with-all-references-recursively)

Method CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap returns you transparent proxy from your typeof(????).FullName. So you should:

1. create some class which inherited from MarshalByRefObject in your importing dll
2. use typeof(%yourNewMarshalByRefClassNameFrom1%).FullName

Comment: I tried the top answer on that question and kept gaving me and error when I do `value.GetAssembly(ReferenceDll)`....  Could not load file or assembly `Gamers_V1_0_0, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`.

Comment: Try to check your local directory path it maybe different. `var currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var assemblyFullPath = Path.Combine(currentDir, "assembly name");`

Comment: I have tried `if(File.Exists` however it's passes that and gives me a same error

Comment: Maybe assembly has got some dependencies and they didn't copy to build folder?