# How do I reference an EF Configuration in another project via reflection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I'm trying to create a console application for generating a SQL Migration script for automation purposes - the same script generated by:

Update-Database -Script

From Package Manager Console.

In the console app I've created I can generate the script if I reference the DLL directly that has my DBMigrationsConfiguration in it.

For example this works:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure;
using System.IO;
using TAPS.Infrastructure.Migrations;

namespace msg
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
            var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
            var sql = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(null, null);            
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\script.sql", sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have a direct reference to the DLL, a using statement and I use a new statement to instantiate the Config object.

Now if I try to do it via reflection I get back null from the line:

```
DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration = (DbMigrationsConfiguration)assembly.CreateInstance("TAPS.Infrastructure.Migrations, Configuration");
```

The full code sample follows that I'm trying to get working via reflection:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace msg
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\DLLPath\TAPS.Infrastructure.dll"));
            DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration = (DbMigrationsConfiguration)assembly.CreateInstance("TAPS.Infrastructure.Migrations, Configuration");            
            var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
            var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
            var sql = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(null, null);            
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\script.sql", sql);
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration variable comes back as null.

Comment: Remove your screen capture and just copy paste your code here, please.

Comment: CodeNotFound - I was trying to show the add DLL reference but I went ahead and took out the screen shots and added just the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixed it:

```
class ProxyDomain : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        try
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

From @shytikov answers at:

[How to Load an Assembly to AppDomain with all references recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658498/how-to-load-an-assembly-to-appdomain-with-all-references-recursively)

Answer (score 1):

If the Configuration type is in the TAPS.Infrastructure.Migrations namespace you need to get it like this with reflection, the syntax you are using is wrong.

```
var foo = assembly.CreateInstance("TAPS.Infrastructure.Migrations.Configuration");
```

Try this to loop through all the types in your loaded assembly, the name must match.

```
foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(type);
}
```

Comment: If I try this the GetTypes() gives me an error of: {"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."}

In the LoaderExceptions it refers to another DLL that I've tried loading in addition with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load but that doesn't fix the problem.  Odd that if I just add a reference I only need the one DLL.  Suggestions?

Comment: The reference for the TAPS.Infrastructure.Migrations is most likely Copy to Local = true, thus all the required dlls are copied along, are there some types that are used in the configuration? Are both applications using same version of entity framework and target framework?

Comment: I see what you are saying now - when I add the single reference to my console app it's also copying additional DLLs to my BIN directory behind the scenes.  I guess my question is now - how do I automatically load those also?

If I just addin an additional AppDomain Load such as:

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Development\eTaps\Dev\Source\TAPS.Web\bin\TAPS.Core.dll"));
            
It still says that Taps.Core.Dll is not loaded when I try to CreateInstance.

Comment: I got it to work!  You defiantly pushed me in the right direction.  Thanks.